# how to use models to take an input as a file from user in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have just started learning django.
I am not able to understand how to use the models for input from user on the screen. The required fileinput field is not being displayed on the server page

**views.py**

```
def initial(request):
  return render(request,'display/home.html')

def upload(request):
    f = FileForm()
    f=FileModel.objects.all()
    print(f)
    y="Hello"

    if request.method== 'POST':
        fil=FileForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if fil.is_valid():
            newfile=FileModel(file=request.FILES['file'])
            newfile.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('display.views.list'))
    else:
           fil=FileForm()

    docs=FileModel.objects.all()



    return render(request,"display/upload.html",{"y":y})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class FileModel(models.Model):
    file=models.FileField(upload_to='C:/..../csvg/')
```

Comment: I don't know what guide you are following, but it is clearly outdated. I strongly suggest you follow the [official guide](https://www.djangoproject.com/start/) of the latest Django release instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing the form to the template, so the template can't display it.